# Having Issues with Bluetooth-pulgin in NativeScript: ERROR TypeError: ... is not a function?

Tags: angular, nativescript, android-bluetooth, angular2-nativescript

I am currently trying to learn the Bluetooth connection in NativeScript using this code that I got from Github.
Everything is fine so far.
But after I run the app, I get this error message "ERROR TypeError: bluetooth.startScanning is not a function" and now I don't know how to solve this or what the problem is. The error message does not appear for the programmer who programmed this app.

I would appreciate your help.

Blutooth.connection.ts

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BleDevice } from '../models/ble-device.model';
    var bluetooth = require('nativescript-bluetooth');


    @Injectable()
    export class BluetoothConnection {
      bleDevicesAround: Array<BleDevice> = new Array;

      write(bluetoothMessage): void {
          console.log('Writing message: ' + JSON.stringify(bluetoothMessage));
          bluetooth.write(bluetoothMessage)
              .then((result) => console.log("Value written " + JSON.stringify(result)),
              (error) => console.log("Write error: " + error));
      }

      fixPermission(): void {
          bluetooth.hasCoarseLocationPermission()
              .then((granted) => {
                  console.log("Has location permission ? " + granted);

                  if (!granted) {
                      bluetooth.requestCoarseLocationPermission()
                          .then(() => console.log("Location permission requested"));
                  }
              });
      }

      connect(UUID: string): Promise<any> {
          return bluetooth.connect({
              UUID: UUID,
              onConnected: (peripheral) => {
                  console.log("Periperhal connected with UUID: " + peripheral.UUID);
                  peripheral.services.forEach(function (service) {
                      console.log("Service found: " + JSON.stringify(service));
                  });
              },
              onDisconnected: (peripheral) => {
                  console.log("Periperhal disconnected with UUID: " + peripheral.UUID)
              }
          });
      }

      disconnect(UUID: string): void {
          bluetooth.disconnect({ UUID: UUID })
              .then(() => console.log("Disconnected successfully"),
              (err) => console.log("Disconnection error: " + err));
      }

      scan() {
          console.log('Scanning...');
          this.bleDevicesAround = new Array;
         
            return bluetooth.startScanning({
                serviceUUIDs: [],
                seconds: 3,
                onDiscovered: (device) => {
                    const bleDevice = new BleDevice(device.UUID, device.name, device.state);
                    this.bleDevicesAround.push(bleDevice);
                }
            });
      }
    }
```

where the method is used:

```js
bleDevicesAround: Array<BleDevice> = new Array;
connectToMagicBlue() {
            this.bluetoothService.scan().then(() => {
                console.log('Scanning completed');
                this.magicBlue = this.getMagicBlue();
                if (this.magicBlue) {
                    console.log('Magic blue found');
                    this.bluetoothService.connect(this.magicBlue.UUID)
                        .then((device) => console.log('Connected: ' + JSON.stringify(device)));
                } else {
                    console.log('Device not found');
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: I might be able to help since my app uses nativescript-bluetooth 3.0.0. What version of nativescript-bluetooth are you running? Depending on your version, you might no need ServiceUUIDs in your startScanning function.